# How to get better graphics at Toshiba C660?

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, toshiba-satellite

Recently I installed Ubuntu 11.10 using wubi at my laptop Toshiba C660-1C8 (with built-in Intel HD Graphics). When I previously used Windows, I had many drivers from Toshiba including Display Driver installed. Graphics was very good. But there is no drivers for linux from Toshiba.

Now at Ubuntu my graphics is very granular, blurred, with low contrast. Are there drivers that can help me? How can I make my graphics better?

Resolution is set to native 1366x768 at both Windows and Ubuntu

Comment: You should probably post the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A1 VGA`. Not all Intel GPUs are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that Toshiba (and other OEMs) don't write any drivers for their laptops, but rather re-distribute whatever Intel, Rbroadcom, Realtek, Nvidia, and others provide them with.

Intel has its GPU driver built into the Linux kernel, so that you don't have to search, install and troubleshoot anything. Unfortunately, the Linux driver compares poorly to its Windows counterpart. It under performs, causes xserver crashes, lacks power management features, etc. To get a better driver, you have to wait for Intel to release one, hopefully sooner rather then later, though honestly, I wouldn't hold my breath just yet.